# Filter out pages from structured navigation

Tags: sharepoint-designer, navigation

I'm setting up structured navigation to show in my site master page. But i want to hide any pages from the Pages or Site Pages Library. I just want the links that i've created on the Area Navigation Settings page, so i hid the other pages in the Area Navigation Settings page, but they are still visible at the menu. What should i do?

Here is the screeshot of the result, i just want the items surrounded by red:
[image: Current navigation result]

And here is the configuration on the Area Navigation Settings page:
[image]

My site is in Portuguese, but (Oculto) = (Hidden).

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of navigation settings under AreaNavigationSettings.aspx.

1. Global Navigation
2. Current Navigation

Global navigation refers to the Top navigation menu and the current navigation is what appears on the left sidebar. For both types of settings, there's an option to show or hide pages. Uncheck that option and hit 'OK' to apply the changes. To manually hide/delete a link from structured nav use Structural Navigation: Editing and Sorting section.

For 'MySite', you need to apply the changes to the MySite host site collection.

Comment: I already did exactly this, but it didn't work! And i don't know why! I've unchecked the show pages option for both and the pages are still there visible on the navigation

Comment: can you add a screenshot?

Comment: Ok! I added to the original post!

Comment: Can you try deleting a link? ex. delete 'Template' and see if anything changes on the left nav.

Comment: The delete option is not enabled when i select the links that i want to delete

Comment: From the screenshot you posted, it seems like you're using Global navigation but it's vertical instead of being horizontal (default). Did you make changes to your master page and modified the 'DataSourceId'? Try switching your master page to default master page and see if the issue persists.

Comment: I've made changes to the master page but i didn't change the DataSourceId of the asp menu. When i switched the site master page back to the default, the navigation worked well, but when i switched back to mine, it stopped working

Comment: I decided to use to Managed metadata navigation. Now it is working well!